# get the image with the audio file

Tags: android, media-player, media

i m going to play media file i got most of content of audio files.i want image of media files. i m using following fragment of code for getting audio files content.i could not get the image with the media file.so please help me to get audio files album image.

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                          MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                          MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                          MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
                          MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                          MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                          MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER,
                          MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION                              

                         };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here i can attach one function that is return album art from media store . Here in function we just have to pass the album_id which we get from Media store .

```
 public Bitmap getAlbumart(Long album_id) 
 {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try 
    {
        final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
            .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);

        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver()
            .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

        if (pfd != null) 
        {
            FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
return bm;
}
```

Comment: int albumId = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);

Comment: "content://media/external/audio/albumart" looks hard-coded. Any way to get this using MediaStore.Audio.Albums.XXXXX ? :)